# Insertion in indexDB with keyPath

Tags: javascript, database, indexeddb

The following code snippet showing `alert("Added")` but nothing has been added to the indexDB. There is one entry in my indexDB but I am unable to add more entries.

```
var transaction = db.transaction("movies", "readwrite")
  .objectStore("movies") // keypath is also there :{keyPath: "imdbID"}
  .add(movieDetailObject);

  transaction.onsuccess = function(event) {
      alert("Added");
  };

  transaction.onerror = function(event) {
      alert("Error");
  }
```

How can I add more entries with `keypath` and object as values?

Comment: `success` and `error` fire at requests (the object returned by `add()`, `get()` etc.) `complete` and `abort` fire at transactions. Errors do bubble up from requests to transactions as a reporting convenience, but are more informative when you understand which request is failing. You'll never see a `success` event on a transaction.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to tell without the surrounding code, but the keyPath is probably the same for each entry.

Just for good practice, you should also listen to the events that can fire on the IDBRequest that's returned by `.add(movieDetailObject)`, to see if onsuccess or onerror fires.